# Removing keys from selector

Tags: java, nio

I'm trying to implement NIO-server and have a question about  `SelectionKey`. Suppose we extracted some key that's ready for read. Like this:

```
SelectionKey key;
//...
SocketChannel c = (SocketChannel) key.channel;
//read from c
```

But what we read from the channel is not enough to make a complete `Packet`. So I attach some object to the `key`.

Question: When should I remove the `key` from a `Selector`? When I read the complete `Packet`? Or every time I should re-register the channel, delete the key from `Selector` and reattach data that was received to the newly registered `SelectionKey`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When should I remove the key from a Selector?

When you are no longer interested in events from its `Channel`. This is rare. Most often you just close the `Channel`, which automatically cancels the `SelectionKey`.

> When I read the complete Packet?

No, why?

> Or every time I should re-register the channel, delete the key from Selector

No, why? If you're interested in read events from the channel, why would that interest ever stop until you close the `Channel`? Other than the case where you're getting short writes to that channel, in which case you should certainly stop being interested in reading it: but you can do that by manipulating the `interestOps` as below.

> and reattach data that was received to the newly registered SelectionKey?

I have no idea what this means. There is really no reason to register a new `SelectionKey` for an existing channel. Just play around with its `interestOps`, possibly setting them to zero if you aren't interested at all for some reason.